# how to Compare list element in order to get the maximum value?

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to compare a list element and get the max value but without the value of 65533 which represent 0 in my program.
With this code I always have the same max value which is not normal. can someone correct my errors or advise me.

```
int a = text.charAt(39), b = text.charAt(40), c = text.charAt(41), d = text.charAt(42);

            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d);

            Integer max = Collections.max(list);

            if ((a >= 5 & a!=65533) || (b >= 5 & b!=65533) || (c >= 5 & c!=65533) || (d >= 5 & d!=65533)) {

                if (max == a) {
                    Defauts_detecteur.setText(R.string.Défaut_récurrent_1);
                } else if (max == b) {
                    Defauts_detecteur.setText(R.string.Défaut_récurrent_2);
                } else if (max == c) {
                    Defauts_detecteur.setText(R.string.Défaut_récurrent_3);
                } else if (max == d) {
                    Defauts_detecteur.setText(R.string.Défaut_récurrent_4);
                }

                Conseil_detecteur.setText("Par mesure de sécurité, nous vous conseillons\nvivement de vérifier que le détecteur est bien\n collé au produit à sécuriser.\n\nPour une adhésion optimale,\nremplacez l’adhésif. Vérifiez que le détecteur est bien connecté à la centrale et qu’il est en bon état.");
            } else {
                Conseil_detecteur.setText("Oops ! Il semblerait que vous ayez rencontré quelques alarmes intempestives. \n" +
                        "\nPour une maintenance\n préventive de votre système, \n" +
                        "\ncontactez notre hotliner au 02 37 33 69 66\n");
                Defauts_detecteur.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Collections.max(Collection)` method gives you the largest element according to the collection elements' `Comparable.compareTo` method.

But your element type is `Integer` which uses the natural ordering of integers for `compareTo`.

So what you need to do is:

1. Define a `Comparator` that implements your special ordering where `65535` means the same thing as `0`.   (Assuming that is what you mean ...)
2. Use `Collections.max(Collection, Comparable)` to find the maximum of your list.

Comment: Can you write please  an example of the code that you describe?

Comment: There are some examples of comparators here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/.  But I can't code your specific use-case because the description in your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Customer a comparator and and sorted by desc, get the first element is the max value that you want.

```java
    List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(5,3,2,4,1, 65533);
    int v = arr.stream()
            .sorted((a, b) -> {
              int a_ = a == 65533 ? 0 : a;
              int b_ = b == 65533 ? 0 : b;
              return b_ - a_;
            })
            .findFirst().get(); // v = 5
```

Comment: `b_ - a_` is incorrect.  That should be `Integer.compare(a_, b_)`.   Why?  Overflow!  (Plus, the `Stream.max` function would be faster, and`Collections.max` would be faster still.)

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using Optional interface of Stream API, the following statement demonstrates how you use it.
{OptionalInt max = Arrays.stream(strings).mapToInt(String::length).max();}